# Macbook Air mid 2013 with Mavericks stopped connecting to familiar wifi after 10.9.4 update

Tags: macos, network, wifi, macbook-pro

I recently installed update 10.9.4, which was recommended for all Mavericks users. My wifi was working fine beforehand and now won't connect to familiar networks. Ironic much? The 10.9.4 update was supposed to *fix* wifi problems for Mavericks!

I have tried various troubleshooting approaches and nothing works. My mac is able to see the network but not connect to it. When I try, it just says "The network _____ could not be joined" and then gives me the option to run diagnostics, which does not help. I've tried resetting the SMC and PRAM, deleting the contents of the system config folder, and of course have restarted the machine several times. I've deleted the bluetooth config file, deleted and re-added the wifi in network preferences and renewed the DHCP lease. I'm afraid I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I have a Mac Book Pro with 10.6.8, fully functional until yesterday. I've upgraded to 10.9.4 and now the Wi-fi is dead, not even connects or show the avaiable nets. The icon says on tooltip there are no hardware installed.
Please let me know if you got any success. I'll do the same.

Comment: Did you try deleting the misbehaving Wifi network from the list of Preferred Networks in Network Preferences and starting from scratch? Please give a bit more detail about the troubleshooting techniques you tried.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to manually connect to network to see if that works.

Here are the steps how to do that using Terminal by copy/paste following:

Turn On

```
networksetup -setairportpower en0 on
```

Find

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/airport scan
```

Connect

```
networksetup -setairportnetwork en0 WIFI_SSID_I_WANT_TO_JOIN WIFI_PASSWORD
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having regular issues to connect to home wifi network with Maverick 10.9.3. I upgraded to 10.9.4, now i have systematic issue. It takes me at least 10-15 times entering the same password to get connected. But at least at the end i have connection...